# Trouble opening cshtml file

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, razor, crash

I have an mvc project while working on it i have opened a cshtml file, then  unexpectedly my pc was crashed and restarted, now when i want to open the same cshtml file it opens like the image i have shared

[image]

when i open the url in the browser i get this error as bellow image

[image]

any help please

Comment: Try opening it in note pad

Comment: tried nothing showing it is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your question is, since you only describe a problem and not specifically what you are trying to do.

But since it's been 20 minutes and nobody is answering, I'll try to help. (I do not have enough reputation to post a comment, or I would have)

The screen in your sample is Visual Studio's binary editor. Your file seems to contain only zeroes, no data. That probably means the file is corrupt. I assume Visual Studio defaults to the binary editor in this case because the file does not contain any text that is possible to display.

I think you'll have to delete the file and restore it from your source control system. (Hopefully you didn't have a lot of work in that file, because it is probably gone.)

Comment: Thanks for your help you are right it contains nothing , but luckily i have source control version, and about your reputation i will make your answer as correct one not only to up your reputations also for trying to help.